# api blueprint mock data - ensuring tests are valid

Tags: mocking, apiblueprint

I've adopted using API blueprint for our documentation on a project, it's great.  I'm struggling with one thing which is probably simple but I can't conceptualize it:
How do I ensure that my API endpoint, connected to a shared database, will always provide a known set of data?

I could visualize it this way: ensuring that the order of my HTTP actions are all in sequence, for example (pseudo-code, not actual api blueprint syntax):

`POST /user
{user_name: 'foo'}`

returns `{id:1}`

`GET /user/1`

returns `{user: 'foo'}`

`PUT /user/1
{user_name: 'bar'}`

returns `{id: 1}`

`DELETE /user/1`

returns `{delete: 'success'}`

Has anyone else solved this problem, unfortunatley I cannot ensure the state of my backend database to which the API is connected which is why I am facing these inconsistency issues.  Some of our team has been writing a doc spec which satisfies the GET portion, given they manually enter records (they have not yet created the POST logic, for example) but as soon as we switch our backend DB GET user/1 will not always return 'foo'.  Hope this makes sense, please let me know if I should edit my question for clarity.

Comment: Are you saying you do not have control over the schema in your backend database? Or you don't have control over the implementation of the API endpoints? You say shared ___ but word is missing above. Not clear exactly what the issue is. Your implementation above implies that you can put or post multiple structures and get a different structure as desired functionality.

Comment: Basically, I'm having developers write up API blueprints prior to making endpoints.  They've been starting with GET and putting in a response for what they *should* be getting for GET user/1, however, depending on what database they're connected to that data may be different.  I was thinking that if we implemented POST first, then  the same data we are using in API blueprint for a a POST could be used to compare on a GET for the returned ID @Zdenek does this make any sense?

Comment: Hey Charles, I am not quite sure if I understand what the issue is. Are you expecting the answer with correct value from the Apiary mock server or is this more about testing the API with a tool such a Dredd?

Comment: What you write in the blueprint are just mere example values, they may or may not be returned from the backend. When it comes to testing, our tool is not comparing the exact values of these examples, rather, it checks for the presence of the attributes (json fields). Not sure if this answer your question tho.